# No module named jinja2, yet it's installed

Tags: python, jinja2

When I run `sudo pip install jinja2` I see: `Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2 in /Users/rose/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg`.

Yet running `import jinja2` in a new python 2.7 shell gives: `ImportError: No module named jinja2`

Comment: is it on your python path?

Comment: The default search path is always appended to the PYTHONPATH. The default search path begins with `prefix/lib/pythonversion`, as mine does.

Comment: Have you tried `import sys; print sys.path` to verify that your paths are fine? There's definitely something weird going on. Alternatively, `pip uninstall jinja2` then `pip install jinja2` again. Or try using a virtual env and installing jinja2 into that..

Comment: I try to `cd` into `~/Library/Python`, but I get permission denied, so I `sudo cd ~/Library/Python`, and that does nothing. No cd happens. I've never seen this before. `sudo ls -l ~/Library/Python` gives `drwx------`

Comment: Could pip and python be picking up different interpreters?  What do `which python` and `pip -V` show?

Comment: I'm surprised there's a ~/Library/Python, usually it's at /Library/Python

Comment: You want pip --version not pip -V

Comment: @dmcaulslan `which python`: `/usr/bin/python`. `python --version`: `Python 2.7.5`. `pip -V`: `pip 1.4.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)`

Answer (score 12):

Note that Jinja2 is installed in your home directory, and that Python's site-packages directory is located a `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. It's likely that either `/Users/rose/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/` is not contained in your Python path, or Python does not have access to this directory. This may be the result of installing Jinja2 with `pip install jinja2` instead of `sudo pip install jinja2`.

You can check if `/Users/rose/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/` by opening your Python shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

If not, the easiest solution may simply be to reinstall Jinja2 as admin:

```
pip uninstall jinja2
sudo pip install jinja2
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest solution by Mark Edge didn't worked for me, as pip installed  jinja2 to place-not-in-path anyway.

Here is my development of solution:

1. If you don't know or forgot where pip install jinja2, use `pip install jinja2` again. You are going to get something like *Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages* , and that's the path you need.
2. There should be .bash_profile file in your home directory ( /Users/Your_username).

I added to it:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PATH"
PYTHONPATH="$HOME/Scripts/:$PATH"
```

If you already have PYTHONPATH line like above, add just the export one.

Restart your shell/Terminal windows for them to pick the new path.

Doing that fixed my problem "No module named jinja2"

Comment: you don't have to restart terminal window, just `source .bash_profile`.

Comment: How to do the same on windows

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem.  I have both `python2` and `python3` installed (on MacOS), and was trying to run under `python2` (this being the default version).  It appears that `pip` defaults to `python3`.  The fix for me was simple:

```
pip2 install jinja2
```

I also notice that this problem does not arise when using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

I was putting my script into a Dockerfile when I ran into this. Turned out my `#!/usr/bin/python3` was triggering a different instance of python. The `FROM python:3` python3 binary was running from /usr/local/bin/python3 in the path.

Instead of running as:

```
RUN ./myscript.py
```

I went with:

```
RUN python3 ./myscript.py
```